# Domain Driven Design: How to handle a conceptually large aggregate root?

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design, one-to-many, aggregateroot

I am trying to model a very simple domain which has the conceptual (one)PARENT --> (many)CHILD. The problem being that the number of children in the relationship may be in the millions.

I'm trying to construct an aggregate root that will allow me to "put" (update or insert if doesn't exist) a single child at a time. However, the values being updated must be validated beforehand by the parent.

What patterns can I use to approach this? Currently I have considered the following:

**PARENT as aggregate root**

- +Validation is simple as children are accessed via parent
- -Non performant as may have to retrieve millions of children in order to update just one
- +/- Can I do lazy loading? I read allot of articles that this is a DDD anti-pattern due to consistency concerns

**CHILD as aggregate root**

- +Performant as only retrieving the data to update
- -Validation because non trivial, either the parent must be an entity of the root, or the root must be externally provided the parent to do validation. Both options cause issues:

  - Because the update is "put" style, the first option makes creation of the child hard (if I implement creation in the repository's find(id) method, then I don't have the necessary information to construct the child, and if I put it in the service calling the repository then I don't have a way to access the parent information as its not a aggregate root).
  - The second option causes consistency issues, i.e. I could provide a parent that is not a parent of the child being updated.

**BOTH as aggregate roots**

- +/- How do I ensure consistency, i.e. child is validated by its actual parent?

Comment: This answer might help you take a decision: 
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/274404/149373

Answer (score 1):

You haven't understood what an aggregate root (AR) is. It isn't a parent container for children. It's s concept where *has* should be handled as *is defined by* . One to many has nothing to do with identifying an AR.

A "child" is a concept that makes sense to exist in AR context i.e it's part of the aggregate represented by the AR. Your example seems to define a repository, a container of items. And it does look a bit like CRUD functionality.

Are you sure you are in an aggregate and not in a context where a simple service is enough?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I haven't chosen the aggregate root yet (which is the point of my question) so its not that i'm implying the parent in the relationship should be the aggregate root because its a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you the exact scenario as its business sensitive, I guess a close example would be trying to model a brain. A brain is made up of billions of neurons, so if you have brain as your AR you potentially have a performance issue as its not feasible to retrieve all neurons when you want to activate some behaviour of a brain. If I make the neuron the AR, then its not trivial to validate its behaviour and there is the issue of creating new neurons within a brain. Which should be the AR, or should there be some other AR to encapsulate these?

Comment: A neuron is an intrinsic part of the brain (afaik, biology is not my forte).A brain wouldn't function without neurons. So, does your AR really needs those children to be valid, to work properly as expected from the concept OR it just holds things together? You are speaking about retrieving things. I think you do want a repository, not an AR. With a proper AR retrieving only 1 child wouldn't make sense. And it does matter in what use cases it's needed. Things are not straight forward in DDD modelling, you need to knows exactly what the domain means.

Comment: And btw, we're trying to model concepts and use cases as they make sense for the business, not accurate real life depiction of how business or an object is. Things are quite tricky.

Comment: In the brain example I am implying more than one bounded context. I.e. there exist some context where the brain is the AR. The brain problem can't be represented by solely a repository as that defines no behaviour in your conceptual model. Assume in another context I want to call a behaviour of brain that requires knowledge of one neuron, say to update the state of said neuron in a non trivial way. How would you model that in a performant way such that you avoid retrieving all neurons owned by the brain? What would be your AR?

Comment: I get your point about not modeling real life, the brain example is just some arbitrary problem as I can't discuss the actual domain in detail as mentioned. So ignore the real world analogies.

Comment: Set the AR as the Universe and be done with it - one aggregate to rule them all....my precious